# Start ssh using systemctl inside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I' m  a beginner in the Docker;
I have pulled a CentOS 7 image from Hub and ran it ;

I need to  ssh in to the docker container(CentOS 7) from my host.

Got the docker container's IP using `docker inspect container-id`

I have installed the following using

```
 initscripts
 systemd.x86_64                           
 systemd-libs.x86_64                          
 open-ssh
 firewalld
 net-tools
```

when i tried to start the firewall to open the port for ssh(22)

```
[root@a6f3e3eb095c ~]# systemctl  start firewall
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
```

Also tried,

```
[root@a6f3e3eb095c ~]# /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system &
[1] 353
[root@a6f3e3eb095c ~]# systemd 219 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 -SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
Detected virtualization xen.
Detected architecture x86-64.

Welcome to CentOS Linux 7 (Core)!

Set hostname to <a6f3e3eb095c>.
Cannot determine cgroup we are running in: No such file or directory
Failed to allocate manager object: No such file or directory

[1]+  Exit 1                  /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system
```

How to start the firewall/ssh inside the docker container ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: [If you run SSHD in your Docker containers, you're doing it wrong!](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/) from @jpetazzo.

Comment: ok. how to start a application inside the docker container using `systemctl`

Comment: I double the comment from @tgogos . Most likely you shouldn't run neither sshd, nor firewall, nor systemd inside the container.

Comment: @soundararajan.c What do you want to run inside the container and why CMD or ENTRYPOINT is not enough?

Comment: use **service** instead of **systemctl**

Answer (score 0):

inside docker container run following commands :

```
yum update -y glibc-common

yum install -y sudo passwd openssh-server openssh-clients tar screen crontabs strace telnet perl libpcap bc patch ntp dnsmasq unzip pax which

rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

yum install -y hiera lsyncd sshpass rng-tools

service sshd start; 

sed -i 's/UsePAM yes/#UsePAM yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; 

sed -i 's/#UsePAM no/UsePAM no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; 

sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config; 

sed -i 's/enabled=0/enabled=1/' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo

mkdir -p /root/.ssh/; 

rm -f /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock; 

echo "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" > /root/.ssh/config; 

echo "UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" >> /root/.ssh/config

echo "root:password" | chpasswd
```

( or )

Simply you can pull docker image of centos with ssh in docker hub

https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=centos+ssh&starCount=0

https://hub.docker.com/r/kinogmt/centos-ssh/

https://hub.docker.com/r/jdeathe/centos-ssh/

Comment: `[root@a6f3e3eb095c /]# service sshd start;
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start sshd.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" / aka installing systemd inside a docker by using the https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement ... after that the docker-exec stuff should be all fine to do things inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

If you really do need an **ssh** or **sftp** container, then you can use my [Docker Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jdeathe/centos-ssh/) as a [source image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from) for your own or run it directly:

If using the official [CentOS-7 Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) and you require systemd, there are instructions on how to enable it under the section "Systemd integration".

However, based on the following:

> I need to ssh in to the docker container(CentOS 7) from my host.

You can use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to run commands in a running, (backgrounded), container so, for images that have bash available, you can access an interactive tty and run bash as follows from your host - where container can be either the name or id:

```
docker exec --tty --interactive <container> bash
```

OR

```
docker exec -ti <container> bash
```

Finally, it's unlikely to be necessary to install the firewall package in your image as the operator will decide what ports to publish from those which are exposed and you can make use of [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) to only expose the necessary public facing services.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the Docker CLI, then you can get into the Docker container using the following command

```
docker exec -it containerId bash
```

I am not sure how to ssh into the docker container, but if you want to do basic operation inside the Docker container, you can make use of the above docker command.